# Change orientation of grob background gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-image

I was surprised that the following simple grob created from a vector of colors works almost as requested.

[image]

However, I would like to make the gradient left to right, not top to bottom.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(grid)
grad = colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))(10)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(grad, 
                        width=unit(1,"npc"), 
                        height=unit(1,"npc"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902515/how-to-rotate-an-image-r-raster) can be a good reference, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is `t`

You have to transpose your `grad` vector (input to `rasterGrob`):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
    annotation_custom(rasterGrob(t(grad), 
                                 width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, "npc")))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, why doesn't specifying a viewport in rasterGrob work here?